# How to use the relations between entities for sonata Admin bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I have 3 entities: Company, Parameters and Elements. [image: ERD diagram of my entities]

**EDIT**

I need to create a page on which each company can fill all Parameters.
Parameter entity is option for field. It have 4 types (text, checkbox, radio, select).

So when I use the `->add("elements", new NeededType())` in ParameterAdmin, I have all the elements of all companies for this parameter, but only required for one company. When I create a custom field type, I'm faced with the problem of filtering. In this way, I use Company-> Parameter-> Element and I think this is easier then other way.

When I use the `->add ("elements")` in CompanyAdmin, I have all the elements of all parameters for this company. And now I need to separate these elements between the parameters and provide them with the required fields. Now I am faced with the problem of multiple types in a single field.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for Google translate. My grammar is very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actuallly found solution. It is EAV Model. Nice gide [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/davidm/articles/12117.aspx).
It was needed to create entity with composit primary key.